# LuaTeX tex->dvi conversion code

Tags: luatex, tex-core, dvi

I'm researching ways to teach computers to generate LaTeX code from Page Description Languages (PDL) like PostScript and PDF, using Machine Translation.

For this to work, it would be majorly useful to have a corpus of aligned LaTeX<->PDL sentences.

I've looked through the LuaTeX source for some time now, searching for the location where TeX token lists are translated to DVI output. I'm hoping that it's possible to modify the source to dump both the token list and generated DVI here, which would result in an aligned TeX<->DVI corpus. I can't for the life of me figure out where this is supposed to reside, or even if TeX tokens work in a way that allows dumping them aligned with their DVI output.

tl;dr: where does LuaTeX perform the actual translation of TeX token lists to DVI, and would it be possible to correlate these token lists to generated DVI code?

Comment: iiuc, that should be TeX's "intestines" (the fourth, visual processor in _TeX by Topic_ terminology), but I fear it is way too low level to be actually useful...